# How to implement a stack with a std::vector?

Tags: c++, vector, stack

I'm trying to understand how to push, pop and get the top of a std::vector, which is basically an implementation of a stack in c++ with vectors.

My implementation is fully working but I'm not completely sure it's handling resources as it should, if it's ok, great. I haven't found many examples of this so it will help others, if it's not ok please provide info on how to improve it, errors that may arise, etc.

This is my current code:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Estado>> vecEstados;
// PUSH
void push(Estado *es){
vecEstados.emplace_back(es); // (MENU IS A SUBCLASS OF ESTADO)
}
// GET TOP
Estado *get_top()
{
    return vecEstados.back().get();
}
// POP (THIS SHOULD JUST ERASE LAST ITEM)
void pop()
{
    vecEstados.erase(vecEstados.end()-1);
}
```

Comment: There's already [`std::stack`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack)

Comment: I may have to modify, insert and do stuff with items which are not the top eventually. That's why I choose to build it with vector

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**PUSH:** Use `push_back` instead of `emplace_back`, if you pass an element with the correct type. `emplace_back` makes *explicit* constructors *implicit*. So use it only if there is a reason. You have to use `std::move` with `std::unique_ptr`, because `std::unique_ptr` is not copyable.

```
vecEstados.push_back(std::move(es));
```

If you create a new element, you can use `std::make_unique` if it is available (C++14). However, in this case it doesn't really matter:

```
vecEstados.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Menu>());
vecEstados.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Estado>(new Menu{}));
```

**TOP:** If you do not intend to modify the returned object, then make the function `const`. For consistency I would return a `std::unique_ptr<Estado>` instead of a `Estado*`.

```
const std::unique_ptr<Estado>& get_top() const
{
    return vecEstados.back();
}
```

**POP:** You should use `pop_back` to remove the last element of a `std::vector`. You can also declare the function with `noexcept`, because it makes it easier to write correct cleanup code.

```
void pop() noexcept
{
    vecEstados.pop_back();
}
```

Comment: I tried to replace emplace_back with push_back however I got error `no matching function for call to 'std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Estado> >::push_back(std::remove_reference<Estado*&>::type)'|`

Comment: I implemented both the top and pop solutions without problems, let me know if you know what's wrong with the push

Answer (score 0):

As P0W mentioned, std::stack already exists. I would also agree with nosid's answers.

I guess the exercise is somewhat redundant, but to mimic the interface which std::stack provides (or part of it) I would suggest something like:

```
template<class Type>
class LisoStack
{
public:
    LisoStack() : mStack() {}

    // Push onto the top of the stack
    Type push(const Type& val)
    { 
        mStack.push_back(std::move(val));
    } 

    // Get the element at the top
    Type& top()
    { 
        return mStack.back();
    } 

    // Get the element at the top
    const Type& top() const
    { 
        return mStack.back();
    } 

    // Remove the element at the top
    void pop() noexcept
    {
        mStack.pop_back();
    }

private:
    std::vector<Type> mStack;
};
```

1. Template to make the container generic.
2. Replace get_top() with top() and just do .back() to provide the element at the back of the vector (the top of the stack). Provide const and non-const versions.
3. The pop() simply calls vector.pop_back() which does what you want - removes the last element (the top of the stack).
4. As nosid mentioned, prefer push_back() in your case (note that this also maintains compatibility with pre C++11 compilers).  You have the option to implement a separate emplace() function as std::stack provides.